# segue from table view cells that replace detail controller do not fire

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using a `UISplitViewController` for a master/detail app. The master controller presents a table view with different cells that when selected are to replace the detail view controller. When the cell is selected the corresponding replace segues do *not* fire.

You can see in the images below I have a replace segue wired to the table view cell labeled "Province Name."

[image: master controller table-view cells with replace segues] [image]

The `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is invoked, and I can programmatically generate the segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, but I should *not* have to do this! I use push segue's frequently from table-view cells with no problem.

Interestingly enough, if I wire a replace segue to a `UIBarButtonItem` it works just fine (i.e., I do *not* have to programmatically perform the segue). The problem is particular to replace segues wired to table view cells.

Is this a bug or is there something I am overlooking here?

Comment: No, there's no bug, it works for me. You should post the code in your master controller.

Comment: @rdelmar that's just it -- there should be *no code* in the master controller to perform the segue -- it should happen automatically. There is the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, but this is *not* getting called since the segue isn't firing --that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, but there can be code in there that prevents the segue -- for instance, if you register a class inappropriately, it will keep the transition from happening. That's why I wanted to see the code. The segues can be automatic, I tested that, but as you said in your answer, you wouldn't usually do it that way.

Comment: @rdelmar I am not sure what code to post -- it seems like it would only break if I used the wrong cell reuse identifier, but in that case the app would die. If by "register a class" you mean set the class name of the controller in the storyboard, then that's done in IB -- that works fine since the replace segue from the button works properly.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean by register class. I mean the table view method, registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:. There may be other ways to screw up the segue, but I know using that method when you shouldn't, does.

Answer (score 0):

May be you've chosen "Accessory Action" instead of "Selection Segue" while creating a segue?

Comment: I looked over a lot of these kinds of possibilities -- I even wrote another test app -- same problem. I can wire all the other segue flavors to tableview cells, but *not* replace segues. I am just wiring the replace segue to the controller and performing it programmatically .

Answer (score 0):

After working with this for awhile, I think I have a clue as to why replace segues are *not* automatic for table view cells. Much of the time, the current detail view controller is the right kind -- you just want to change its "detail item." Only when you need a detail controller of a different kind, then (and only then) do you want to perform the segue to replace the the current detail view controller. So I link the replace segue with the master view controller (instead of the table cell) and use the following logic which only performs the segue if a new controller is truly needed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ...

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {  // Canadian Province
        if ([self.detailViewController isKindOfClass:[ProvinceDetailViewController class]]) {
            self.detailViewController.detailItem = 
                          [appDelegate.provincesDictionary objectForKey:place];
            self.detailViewController.title = place;
        } else {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ProvinceSegue" sender:self];
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

P.S. If you are using replace segues for split view controllers make sure the split view delegate is *not* the detail view controller (which is the way the Xcode template arranges things). I create a standalone delegate object that sends notifications when the associated delegate methods are invoked. This seems to work rather well.

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that you shouldn't make the detail controller the delegate. Sometimes it makes sense to do so, but you do need to make sure you make the new detail controller the delegate, and implement the delegate methods (or have all your detail controllers inherit from a common class that does that).

Comment: @rdelman I made a common detail controller subclass that handles the button and popover dance, but I felt nervous about rerouting the delegate. On hindsight, I suppose that would be fine, but using notifications seemed quite elegant for this.

Comment: I also make sure to hand off the `barButtonItem` and `masterPopoverController` from the old detail controller to the new detail controller (assuming they're not `nil`).